# Error: Could not find or load main class in Sublime Text 3

Tags: java, sublimetext3

Im kind of new to Java and I just made a new class along with a Build System:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZIiL.png)
However, when i go to run my program, it says Error: Could not find or load main class Unit1
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXWZD.png)

What can i do?

I have already gone through a plethora of potential solutions by changing the path in system variables but to no awail.

Comment: Please copy your code here instead of posting images so that we can see exactly what's going on

Comment: [*Please do not post text as images*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool (`{}` button) to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, cannot be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments, and cannot be copied for testing and debugging purposes. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.